# Single entry for segment_2

Tags: 404

I use the following code for a single entry:

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="pages"
entry_id="24"
limit="1"
require_entry="yes"
dynamic="no"
disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
}
{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
{page_body}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It works as expected for segment_1 urls (i.e. www.someurl.com/about-us), but if the template is not the index page of a template group, the same code throws a 404 error (i.e. www.someurl.com/abount-us/leadership).

If I remove limit="1" & require_entry="yes", it works fine.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry) of `require_entry` parameter:

> This parameter tells the channel tag that it should expect the URL to contain a valid entry ID or a valid URL title. If an ID is not found in the URL, the tag will not display any data. Normally, the channel tag will show something, even if the URL doesn’t point to a particular entry. For example, your main channel page will typically show several of your most recent entries. Whereas your “single entry” pages, like your comment page, will show a single entry based on information in the URL. However, if one of your single entry pages is requested, but it doesn’t contain a valid ID, this parameter will tell the tag that you do not wish the template to display anything.

So, you shouldn't and don't need to use the both parameters `entry_id` and `require_entry` together. The strange behavior you're experiencing on your code looks like a conflict.

If you use the parameters `entry_id` or `url_title`, the `no_results` will work fine even without the parameter `require_entry`.

In my opinion, you should prefer to use the [pages module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/pages/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still seems odd that it works on some templates but not others. I do not like the pages module. It's pretty clunky for clients to use. From what I have read, it seems most developers do not use the pages module.

Comment: This doesn't seems odd because, by default, segment_1 is never used to search for an entry. The entries are searched by the system using segments 2 or 3.

Comment: Ah, yes. Didn't think about that. Thanks!